# Loading data into external table

Tags: oracle

I am trying load data to external table.

**Sample.txt**

```
004500323Z  Batman - Earth 1 Batman     Pop!              FUN11494  0  EB  000001080CM0500  2010045003230
004500333Z  NBX - Oogie Boogie Glow     Pop! Keychain !E  FUN11839  0  EB  000000565  2010045003339
004500356Z  Blacklist - Red Reddington  Pop!              FUN10821  0  EB  000001080CM0500  2010045003568
```

Based on position data has to be loaded into external table.

**External table structure**

```
  CREATE TABLE EX_BOOK
   (    "ISBN_10" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
    "AUTHOR_NAME" VARCHAR2(70 CHAR), 
    "BOOK_TITLE" VARCHAR2(150 CHAR), 
    "PUBLICATION_COMPANY_NAME" VARCHAR2(60 CHAR), 
    "PUBLICATION_DATE" CHAR(6 BYTE), 
    "SORT_1" VARCHAR2(3 CHAR), 
    "SELLING_PRICE" VARCHAR2(9 BYTE), 
    "SORT_2" VARCHAR2(7 CHAR), 
    "ISBN_13" VARCHAR2(13 BYTE)
   ) 
   ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
    ( TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
      DEFAULT DIRECTORY "DAT_DIR"
      ACCESS PARAMETERS
      ( RECORDS DELIMITED BY "\n" CHARACTERSET ZHS32GB18030 BADFILE BAD_DIR : 'CHINESE_BOOK_MASTER_SIMPLIFIED_%p_%a.bad' LOGFILE LOG_DIR : 'CHINESE_BOOK_MASTER_SIMPLIFIED_%p_%a.log' READSIZE 10485760 FIELDS LRTRIM MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL REJECT ROWS
WITH ALL NULL FIELDS ( "ISBN_10" ( 1: 10) CHAR(10) ,"AUTHOR_NAME" ( 11: 80) CHAR(70) ,"BOOK_TITLE" ( 81: 230) CHAR(150) ,"PUBLICATION_COMPANY_NAME" ( 231: 290) CHAR(40) ,"PUBLICATION_DATE" ( 291: 297) CHAR(6) ,"SORT_1" ( 304: 306) CHAR(3) ,"SELLING_PRICE" ( 307: 315) INTEGER EXTERNAL(9) ,"SORT_2" ( 316: 322) CHAR(7),"ISBN_13" ( 323: 335) CHAR(13))         )
      LOCATION
       ( 'Sample.txt'
       )
    )
   REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

But while inserting data to external table unnecessary spaces are appending.

**EX_BOOK**

```
ISBN_10     AUTHOR_NAME BOOK_TITLE            PUBLICATION_COMPANY_NAME PUBLICATION_DATE SORT_1 SELLING_PRICE SORT_2
 0 0 4 5 0   0 3 2 3 Z  B a t m a n   -  E a  r t h 1 B a t m a n Pop!  F U N           1 1
```

How to eliminate these spaces while inserting data?

Comment: You have specified an NLS character set for the source file `ZHS32GB18030` : what is the NLS Character Set of the target DB?

Comment: Yes changed NLS character to **16UTF16** and now data is loading to external table without issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed NLS character set for the source file from **ZHS32GB18030** to **16UTF16**, now data is correctly loading to external table.